# Why Require directive does not work properly on Apache?

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04

I have a virtual machine with Virtualbox in which I installed `Ubuntu 14.04` and `Apache`. I am trying that only my host machine could access to this resource with `Require` directive.

I know that the connection between the virtual machine and the host machine it is correct because if I put on my host machine browser the url `localhost:8080` I can see all the content of the root directory of `Apache`.

The problems comes when I try to use the directive `Require` on a directory inside the root directory. I only want that the host machine will have access to that resource so I add to the `apache2.conf` file these lines:

```
<Directory /var/www/example/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require ip (Here the ipv4 of my host machine)
</Directory>
```

but I do not have access from my host machine to this resource.

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is the (virtual) network configured? You can also check in the access log of Apache to find the right IP adress.

Comment: @Jasper It is on NAT model. I think you refer to this when you say virtual network configured. And how can I check it on the log? Thanks in advance!

Comment: /var/log/apache2/access.log is the default.

Comment: @Jasper Yes I know where the log file is but I mean about what should I find to get the IP that I have to use.

Comment: do you have access to /var/www/example if you remove the Require line?   Make sure that works before trying to lock it down by IP.   Once that is working you can work on which IP to use.  There may be an internal & external IP.  Instead of accessing localhost:8080 try using the IP there to see what works.  Or you may need to Require a range of IPs like this: "192.168.15.0/24".   Also, if you are trying to access via some other port than 8080 you may need to open up the Ubuntu firewall.

Comment: @obi1 Yes, I can access it from my host machine without problems if I remove Require line. And I use the IPv4 IP of my host machine on the Require directive. Could it be a wrong IP?

Comment: Sounds plausible.  Check your Apache access logs as suggested above to see the incoming IP when you access the resource & use that IP in the require directive.   You should see a line for each access request with the incoming IP & the resource accessed.  You should see a line denying your access request when access is denied.

Comment: @obi1 Ok I am going to prove it now and tell it to you.

Comment: @obi1 Ok now it works with a different IP. The same IP that it is on the logs file as you said (and the above comment that I did not see before). But I do not understand very well why it is a different IP. If you could explain me it I will mark your answer as accepted. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Nice!  Glad it is working.  The two IPs are an artifact of the VirtualBox NAT configuration.  You've set up a mini-cloud and in the cloud it's not uncommon for a VM to have an internal IP used by other VMs in its domain and an external IP used by VMs outside of it's domain.  That's why the apache access log is so useful to see the IP in the request.  In the better commercial clouds they may hide the multiple IPs per VM detail from users using DNS & hosttables etc.

Comment: @obi1 I say this because I cannot see this IP when I use `ipconfig` on my host machine but it works with it so it is a bit weird for me.

Comment: Here's another way to think about it, the IP you see on ipconfig is your host machines external IP.  But it's accessing the VirtualBox VM via a different IP - its internal IP specific to the network between them.  You can read the VirtualBox documentation for more information.

Comment: @obi1 Oh so, VirtualBox creates two internal IPs, one internal (to use from the VM to the outside) and one that will be assigned to the VMs or host machines that wants to get something from the VM, right?

Comment: this explains it well.  Check out section 6.3 on Network Address Translation(NAT) https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: Thank you very much @obi1. You have been very helpful. If you want, you can put it as an answer so I could accept it (I cannot accept comments). I think it will be great for your rep. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VirtualBox NAT configuration you are using is causing the http request from your host machine to come into your virtual machine via an internal IP rather than the IP you are expecting.  You'll need to update the Require directive to use this internal IP.  To do this, check your Apache access logs to see the incoming IP when you access the resource.  Use that IP in the require directive. You should see a line for each access request with the incoming IP & the resource accessed. You should see a line denying your access request when access is denied.

Comment: Nice explanation! Thank you again :)